# How to output "explain analyze" result to a table column?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3, sql-execution-plan, explain

I have **my_table** with two text columns: **my_query**, which contains various DML queries in text form; and and **my_explanation**, which is entirely populated with *nulls*.

I'd like to do something like:

```
    UPDATE my_table SET my_explanation = execute explain analyze my_table.my_query
```

So that the **my_explanation** column on each row is updated to contain the textual output of the **explain analyze** of the query contained in its **my_query** column.

I tried making a function with cursors but it didn't work. I'm still learning pgplsql. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

`EXECUTE` is a PL/pgSQL statement; it can't be used in an SQL query, only in a `LANGUAGE plpgsql` function or a [`DO` block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html).

You probably want a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION explain_query(sql TEXT) RETURNS SETOF TEXT AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'EXPLAIN ANALYZE ' || sql;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Because `EXPLAIN` returns multiple rows, you'll need to aggregate the output to fit it into a single record in `my_table`:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_explanation = (
  SELECT string_agg(plan, E'\n')
  FROM explain_query(my_query) plan
)
```